# How to make char array and std::string "in a relationship"?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, unions

I'm looking for a way to associate a char array with a string so that whenever the char array changes, the string also changes. I tried to put both char array and string variables in a union but that didn't worked as the compiler complained...

Any ideas are welcome...

Comment: This sounds very much like an XY question - maybe the right solution is to NOT do that at all?

Comment: You would probably need to implement a C-string wrapper class that has to recalculate parameters every time a method on it is called.  It wouldn't be very efficient, and I can't think of a good reason for needing it.  Can I ask why you are looking for something like this?

Comment: Why the need to manipulate the string as a char array? I'm guessing with a little rewriting, you could get by with just std::string.

Comment: Is all this just to get the bonus features of a `std::string` and plethora of member functionality while still exposing raw data to the world outside of your control? Are you at least getting the idea that perhaps the problems with your "solution" to the unspoken original problem may well-be because the solution itself is suspect? (See Mats' comment).

Comment: You should just use a `std::string`.  You can get a c-string back from it via `c_str()`. You can get at the buffer directly via `data()`. Also it is the C++ way.  Embrace the change:-)

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you're trying to achieve with this idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
    class Observable_CharArray
    {
        char* arr;
        std::function<void(char*)> change_callback;

    public:
        Observable_CharArray(int size, std::function<void(char*)> callback)
        : arr(new char[size]), change_callback(callback){}

        ~Observable_CharArray()/*as mentioned by Hulk*/
        {
            delete[] arr;
        }

        void SetCallback(std::function<void(char*)> callback)
        {
            change_callback = callback;
        }

        /*other member function to give access to array*/

        void change_function()
        {
            //change the array here
            change_callback(arr);
        }

    };

    class Observer_String
    {
        std::string rep;

        void callback(char* cc)
        {
            rep = std::string(cc);
        }

     public:
        Observer_String(Observable_CharArray* och)
        {
            och->SetCallback(std::bind(&callback, this, _1));
        }

        /*other member functions to access rep*/
    };
```

The design can definitely be improved.
There can be other ways to solve your actual problem rather than observing char arrays.

Comment: At the very least you are missing the destructor deleting the array.

Comment: (and you don't really answer the OP's question)

Comment: I missed many other things there... wanted to present the approach for creating an observable class, there is lot of scope for improvement in the code I gave. Also, I did not present the code for observer.

Comment: Your answer should state clearly what your code-snippet is trying to demonstrate, and that it is only a small part of a solution. The way it is now, I fear that it's worse then useless. So if you want to be upvoted, you better edit your answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the std::string may change the string array inside (especially when it resizes). For instance, c_str returns the address of the current string - documentation says that "The pointer returned may be invalidated by further calls to other member functions that modify the object.".

If you're sure you won't call string methods (hence the string will stay at the same memory location), you could try accessing the c_str pointer (your char array) directly and modify its content.

```
std::string str = "test";
char* arr = (char*)str.c_str();
arr[3] = 'a';
```

NOTE: I strongly advice against this unless in a testing context.

In other words, the string class doesn't guarantee it's going to stay in the same place in memory - meaning trying to access it through a char array is impossible.

The best is to create another string class that enforces the char array to always stay the same size (and so can stay in the same memory position all the time). You could also create a bigger array (max size string for instance) to cope with any string size changes - but that should be enforced in your wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

Well you *can* do this, but you shouldn't

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string test("123456789");
   std::cout << test << "\n";
   char* data = &test.front(); // use &(*test.begin()) for pre-C++11 code
   for ( size_t i(0); i < test.size(); ++i )
   {
      data[i] = 57 - i;
   }
   std::cout << test << "\n";
}
```

Output will be

```
123456789
987654321
```

This however goes again everything `std::string` is trying to facilitate for you. If you use `data`, you risk causing UB and changes to `test` may make `data` point to garbage.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this!

However, there are many (dangerous) ways to achieve it:

```
char* cStr = const_cast<char*>(cppStr.c_str());
```

or

```
char* cStr = const_cast<char*>(cppStr.data());
```

or

```
char* cStr = &cppStr[0];
```

But **beware** that the cppStr might be reallocated whenever you touch it, hence invalidating your cStr. That would crash at some point in time, although maybe not immediately (which is even worse).

Therefore, if you are going to do this anyway. Make sure to **cppStr.reserve(SOMETHING)** **before** you get the cStr out of it. This way, you will at least stabilise the pointer for a while.